# Some items of header tag work while others do not

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a new user working on a website. I have taken several udemy classes and made one website that went well. I am now looking to make a second and I am running into an odd problem: some changes to the CSS header tag have an effect on the  header in my index page while other changes do not. For example changing the background color does have an effect, while anything to do with flexbox or padding simply does not cause any change. I am writing this after several sittings and going back to my previous website, hoping someone can help me out. Here is the snippet of my header and the snippet from the css. The code works in the snippet here, but not when I preview! I am using dreamweaver.

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navButton {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    padding: 11px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        
      <div class="logo">
      <img src="Images/smaller GGR Logo.png" width="203" height="114" alt="Gas Guzzler Reviews Logo"/>
        </div>
      
        <nav>
        <div class="navButton"><a href="#">About Us</a></div>
          <div class="navButton"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
        </nav>
    
    </header>
```

My main goal is to have the logo on the left and nav buttons on the right, any help is appreciated!

Comment: it's working find inside the snippet

Comment: EDIT: At first the snippet didnt work for me but now Im seeing it is. And so I started deleting stuff and eventually deleted a line that fixed it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Temani Afif helpfully pointed out the code was working in the snippet. I realised I made an edit from when it did not work in the snippet when I first tested it. I had a CSS Reset after my regular CSS sheet screwing everything up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, you should check the CSS specificity in your code because your code snippet is working just fine to me.

[image: result]

Here is the changes I made to test it.

CSS changes:

```
 .logo {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
    
    .contact__button {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

HTML changes:

```
<div class="navButton contact__button"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
```